# Angular Http Get Call to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angular, httpclient

Trying to learn Angular/ .NET Core, I have an angular front end trying to make an api call but I never hit the api.

The component making the service call

```
 ApiResponse x = this.service.getStuff();
```

```
getStuff(): Observable<ApiResponse>{
   var x = this.http.get<any>('${url}/api/new/getstuff')
              .pipe(retry(1), map(x => x as ApiResponse),catchError(err => this.handleError(err)));
   return x;
}
```

Then on the api side i have

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class newcontroller {

  //controller setup

  [HttpGet("getstuff")]
  public async Task<ApiResponse> returnstuff() {
  //do things
  }
}
```

Comment: Debug the browser. Is the call going where you expect it to go? Can you make the same call using the browser's URL and have it hit the end point? Can you use PostMan and have it hit the end point? You need to do a little troubleshooting on your end first to see what is actually occurring.

Comment: `this.http.get<any>('${url}/api/new/getstuff)`
Is this the code you are using? If so, you are missing a quote at the end of your url.

Comment: Did you `.subscribe()` to the returned observable?

Comment: Agreed, you need to subscribe to the observable, otherwise it won't get called

Comment: So adding the subscribe does call the api, and in the network tab i see the return data, however i never see it on the angular side when debugging, the object i am mapping it to is also undefined